# Python Importing Modules

Tags: python

I have the following app structure. IDE works fine, resolves, but running some scripts gives me

```
  File "/home/sink/TARET/app/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import db
ImportError: No module named app
```

error. I call the module as:

```
import datetime
from app import db


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    RoleID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    ModifiedDate = db.Column(db.DATETIME) and so on
```

What is the correct usage of modules in python?
I have the following structure.

[image]

Ok edit:

db is defined in **init**.py as

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: where's `db` defined? and if `app` is a module, where is the `__init__.py` to define it as a module? In a nutshell: your IDE is wrong, python is right: app does not exists, db even less.

Comment: where is db coming from? There is no db.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the bottom of your app/__init__.py put this:

```
from app import models
```

**Why?**

From http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/

> Circular Imports
>
> Every Python programmer hates them, and yet we just added some:
>   circular imports (That’s when two modules depend on each other. In
>   this case views.py depends on __init__.py). Be advised that this is a
>   bad idea in general but here it is actually fine. The reason for this
>   is that we are not actually using the views in __init__.py and just
>   ensuring the module is imported and we are doing that at the bottom of
>   the file.

Comment: taht actually did it cheers,one more question, i have env.py under alembic folder and i have to call db from __init__.py file, how can i call it from a parent folder?

Comment: You should put the Alembic folder out of the app folder. It's a better design (for me), the migrations is not part of the application at all. Then, you can easyly do a "from app import db"